# What is this twin engine propeller aircraft flying for Garuda airlines in Indonesia in 1983?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Twin propeller small civil aircraft flown by Garuda Airlines Indonesia in 1983.

[image: /]aZxGQ.jpg

Answer (score 6):

Looks to be a Shorts Skyvan.  Sometime called the ‘Flying Shoebox’.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_SC.7_Skyvan

Comment: Not Garuda.. Its in Pelita livery. This company did a lot of charters for the oil industry.\